# How do you initialize val fields with constructor params in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, constructor, variable-assignment, val

In Java you can declare a private final member variable and then initialize it from your constructor, which is very useful and is a very common thing to do:

```
class MyClass {

  private final int widgetCount;

  public MyClass(int widgetCount) {
    this.widgetCount = widgetCount;
  }
```

In Kotlin how do you initialize final member variables (val types) with values passed in to a constructor?

Answer (score 4):

It is as simple as the following:

```kotlin
class MyClass(private val widgetCount: Int)
```

This will generate a constructor accepting an `Int` as its single parameter, which is then assigned to the `widgetCount` property.

This will also generate no setter (because it is `val`) or getter (because it is `private`) for the `widgetCount` property.

Answer (score 4):

As well as defining the `val` in the constructor params, you can use an `init` block to do some general setup, in case you need to do some work before assigning a value:

```
class MyClass(widgetCount: Int) {

  private val widgetCount: Int
  
  init { 
     this.widgetCount = widgetCount * 100
  }
}
```

`init` blocks can use the parameters in the primary constructor, and any secondary constructors you have need to call the primary one at some point, so those init blocks will always be called and the primary params will always be there.

Best to read this whole thing really!
[Constructors](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass(private val widgetCount: Int)
```

That's it. If in Java you also have a trivial getter `public int getWidgetCount() { return widgetCount; }`, remove `private`.

See [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#constructors) for more details (in particular, under "Kotlin has a concise syntax for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor").